# Parser for OpenCSV's CsvToBeanBuilder

Tags: java, opencsv

I have some backslashes in my csv file data.  How do you set a parser (such as rfc4180Parser) in OpenCSV's CsvToBeanBuilder?

```
RFC4180Parser rfc4180Parser = new RFC4180ParserBuilder().build();

List<MyObjVO> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(new InputStreamReader(inInputStream))
        .withType(MyObjVO.class)
        .build()
        .parse();
```

Comment: How to set for what? What's the input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: I want to use a different parser, namely the RFC4180Parser.  The default OpenCSV parser for the reader does not handle '\' the way I would like.  I want to configure the CsvToBeanBuilder to use the RFC4180Parser.